# apache2 caches css

Tags: css, apache, caching

When I change a CSS file and reload the page that includes it, I don't get the changes in my browser.

The only thing that works so far is: rename the css file, rename it back to the original name, reload the web page.

Any ideas what I can do to force apache to give my browser the up-to-date css file?

I have tried:

- adding `ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 second"` to my apache VirtualHost configurations
- `touch mycssfile.css`
- adding a timestamp as parameter after the name of the css file in the href attribute of the link tag. E.g. `href="<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  mycssfile.css?{timestamp}" />`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's cached by your browser, not Apache itself.

To prevent this you can add something like

`ExpiresByType text/css "access minus 1 second"`

to your apache config.

Comment: What makes you think that it's being cached by my browser? And, why would "minus" in stead of "plus" help me here? I'm presuming it's being cached by the server... why else would twice changing the file name on the server help me out if it was being cached on the browser?

Comment: As i remember - Apache do not perform in-memory files caching on server-side. At least by default. Apache just send necessary headers in response to browsers `If-Modified-Since` request header. If you think that the caching was performed server-side - try to request the same file twice with `curl`.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience often the caching is done in the browsers.

Try reloading the webpage pressing Ctrl+Shift+R (or Ctrl+F5 on ie).
This should force browsers to ignore files in the cache.